# Get right alignment when i see view(data.frame)

Tags: r, dataframe, view, alignment

```
test <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(5,6,7))
names(test) <- c('Variable 1','Variable 2')
View(test)
```

As you can see the test all data have left alignment but I want to see right alignment

I just want to see data.frame with right alignment

If you recommend other function for read data.frame with right alignment i will appreciate your kindness

Answer (score 0):

You can set `right = FALSE` parameter in `print`

```
print(test, right = FALSE)

#  Variable 1 Variable 2
#1 1          5         
#2 2          6         
#3 3          7
```

I assume you want data to be left aligned (and not right-aligned) since it is right-aligned by default.

Comment: when i use View function  i want all of vector to be right alignment

print function don't print line(like table)